# How to add relative directory while packaging executable python with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, relative-path, pyinstaller

I have a python project that has a following files tree:

```
\main_dir
    gui.py
    data.py
    \lib
        \files
            file1.txt
            file2.txt
     ... more_dirs and files in lib.
```

The `gui.py` imports `data.py`. `data.py` parses `file1.txt` as part of it constructor.
I want to run `gui.py` as an executable in windows and therefore use pyinstaller.

`data.py` opens `file1.txt` whlie using a relative path: `file1_dir = os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "lib", "files")`

I run the following command:

```
pyinstaller "..fullpath..\main_dir\gui.py" -p "..fullpath..\main_dir\" --runtime-hook "..fullpath..\main_dir\lib"
```

The pyistaller succesfully package `data.py` but when run the executable file I get the following error:

"FileNotFoundError: the system cannot find the path specified: '.\lib\files\'

I tried to change the hook to be `<fullpath>\main_dir\lib\files` but got the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How do I add relative dir & files to the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't need to use `--runtime-hook`, **it's for running another script before your main script starts**, for example if you add `--runtime-hook=file1.py` in your command, the execution order at run time would be: 1) run `file1.py`, 2) run your main script. (Of course they are compiled/packed into an exe file already)

So in your case, you use `gui.py` to import `data.py`, and `data.py` operates on `files` in `lib`. You don't need to include `lib` in your `pyinstaller` command, just put it into same folder with the compiled exe file, it'll automatically look for files as it does in your `data.py`; if you want you could include them (files in lib) as `datas` in your spec file, this way those files will be copied to target folder (same folder where the exe file will be at) on compilation, but it's really not necessary.

Also remove `-p` since all your scripts (`gui.py` and `data.py`) are in same folder, no need to tell `pyinstaller` to search for `imports` in other places.